# ERROR: configparser.NoSectionError: No section: 'detail'

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, pycharm

```
def configreader(section, key):
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read("../ConfigFiles/baseURL.cfg")
return config.get(section, key)
```

Running into 'No section: 'detail'' error when ran the code in pyTest mode but no error when the code is launched by itself (independently).

Comment: Please include code directly into the post, don't like images with code as it makes the content non-searchable.

Comment: Sure, I'll keep that in mind moving forward. I figured out the error. Thanks for viewing the request.

Answer (score 0):

Update: Solved, was a syntax error

config.read("./ConfigFiles/baseURL.cfg")

got rid of '.' to launch the code from a top level folder.

Hope it helps.